# Visual Studio 2015/Linux extension produces a "collect2 : error : ld returned 1 exit status" with Cygwin

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2015, cygwin, ld

I am currently trying the [Linux Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e) of Visual Studio 2015.

I plan to have several target machines using various distribs. So far, my testing machine is a Windows 7 with an up-to-date Cygwin with all needed packages (`openssh`, `g++`, `gdb`...) installed.

The test I'm conducting consists in a very simple C++ "Hello world" file, and the VS projects settings are the default ones.

Everything runs well but the linkage:

- architecture is recognized by Visual Studio
- source files are copied properly to the target machine by the VS extension
- they do compile using g++
- but the process ends up with a `"collect2 : error : ld returned 1 exit status"`

I tried to compile this file on the remote platform, using g++. No problem, an executable is produced and it works.

I absolutely don't get it. Any idea?

---

Details if needed:

- My C++ source file:

  ```
   #include <cstdio>

   int main()
   {
      printf("hello from SandboxLinux!\n");
      return 0;
   }
  ```
- My project settings (remote settings and linker settings, in which I see nothing special):

[image: Project settings]
[image: Linker settings]

- My Visual Studio build log:

[image]

- On the remote machine:

  - `main.cpp` has been properly copied
  - `.o` file is properly produced
  - `.exe` ("`.out`") is not
  - project root, `obj` and `bin` directories follow:

[image]
[image]
[image]

- When using `g++` directly on the remote machine:

  - `g++ main.cpp` terminates silently and produces an `a.exe` that works.
  - Using `g++ -v` does not show anything relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it! Default VS/Linux project options are not suitable for Cygwin:

When switching the VS project build output from "minimal" (the default) to "normal" I could notice there was a problem with the generated `ld` command line:

[image]

```
1>       Link:
1>         Linking objects
1>         Invoking ld
1>         g++ -o "/home/xxxxx/projects/xxxxxx/bin/x86/Release/xxxxx.out" -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack /home/xxxxx/projects/xxxxx/obj/x86/Release/main.o
1>         /bin/ld: unrecognized option '-z'
1>         /bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
1>         collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `-z` option is [not implemented on Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-01/msg00717.html) and [won't be](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-01/msg00719.html). So it has to be removed from the VS linker options where it is used by default:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]
(*Note 1*: the third one has to be manually set to blank as both proposed options use `-z`)
(*Note 2*: all other differences between these two screenshots are not tied to this problem. The first is my `release` configuration, kept by default, where the second is my `debug` configuration, that uses verbose and print-map.)

Now everything runs well:
[image]

The program is properly built, it works, and the link with GDB works fine too in debug mode.

Caveat: this `-z` thing might be an issue when switching from Cygwin to standard Linux platforms later on.